# Bitrix Set a condition in $arFilter on the number of elements in a multiple property

Tags: php, bitrix

The iBlock element has a multiple property. When GetList, you need to set $arFilter with the condition that we take elements whose records in the multiple property are less than 10

Comment: Just drop bitrix.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.